# Node - Post request not really doing anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing a simple MEAN app, and I am currently working on the routes.

In my server.js, I have

```
var express        = require('express');
var multer         = require('multer');
var upload         = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});
var sizeOf         = require('image-size');
var app            = express();
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

// configuration ===========================================
require('./app/models/Purchase');
require('./app/models/Seller');
require('./app/models/User');
// config files
var db = require('./config/db');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port
// mongoose.connect(db.url); // connect to our mongoDB database 

// get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse        application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // parse       application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the      X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files   location /public/img will be /img for users

// routes ==================================================
var routes = require('./app/routes/routes');//(app); // pass our    application into our routes
var price = require('./app/routes/pricing');
var processing = require('./app/routes/processing');
var uploads = require('./app/routes/uploads');
var seller = require('./app/routes/seller');


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/price', price);
app.use('/processing', processing);
app.use('/uploads', uploads);
app.use('/seller', seller);


// start app ===============================================
app.listen(port);   
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);            
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Then, in my route, I have

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Seller = mongoose.model('Seller');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.json({message: 'youre in router.get'});
});
router.post('/registerSeller', function(req,res,next){
        console.log('You made it all the way to seller route!');
        res.json({message: "you did it"});
        next();
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I start my node server, everything goes well. When I use Postman to POST to the above route, it just 'hangs' and eventually gives an error message that it cannot connect. In Postman, I select 'POST' to http://localhost:8080/seller/registerSeller.Clicking 'code', I get

```
POST /seller/registerSeller HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 070cb9b3-992a-ffd6-cede-c5b609bc9ce5
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Looking at the browser's developer tools, it shows a POST being made, and then after a while, it also reads that the POST failed.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Node (now) has debugging support built-in (using Chrome as the UI). I suggest reducing the problem to a [mcve]. As it says on that page, you'll probably find the problem; if you don't, you'll have a much more reasonable thing to share with others to get help.

Comment: Could you also include the Postman call you're using to test with?  Exporting the request as HTTP or cURL by clicking the "Code" link in Postman under the "Send/Save" buttons would help us understand what might be happening.

Comment: why is the word 'user' in the console.log line ? `console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);            user`

Comment: @willwoo That was a simple error. I edited it. Thank you.

Comment: @Brian, done, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are responding and then trying to call the next() function in the router stack.

```
router.post('/registerSeller', function(req,res,next){
        console.log('You made it all the way to seller route!');
        return res.send({message: "you did it"});
        //next(); remove this shit.
});
```

This should work. Express middlewares go in order. So if you need to have a middleware to be called before this function, then you have to put it before in the stack. If you need to do something after this function, forget about the `res.json...` part.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I removed it, saved changes, restarted the server, and the same thing is happening.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: change `res.json ...` to `res.send ... `. Also, do you see the console.log output?

Comment: I did. No change. And no, I'm seeing the console.log output.

Comment: I took your code and made it work without changing anything (except removing that next() and the moongose stuff). Is this all your code? Try to comment out the other routes

Comment: Huh. I did that and it worked! Man, thanks. You narrowed it way down for me. I suppose there's a problem with one of the other routes?

Comment: Surely. Comment one by one and update your question with the troublesome file to have a look

Comment: Last time I'll bother you. I found the problem, it was in my routes.js, it was all messed up. I cleaned up the code, everything works now. Thank you again.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at express-generator. It creates a boilerplate with a nice structure to have your code organized

Comment: Will definitely do. Thanks again for everything. This was a learning experience in the truest sense.